# Marsheling issue while replication cache in ehcache

Tags: ehcache, distributed-cache

I am trying to run two node ehcahe cluster on single machine.
I have created two instance of tomcat on machine and used standard manual peer mechanism to replicate cache.
My ehcahe .xml in one app is

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory     class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
```

properties="peerDiscovery=manual, rmiUrls=//172.19.1.99:50002/messageCache|//172.19.1.99:50002/messagesCache" />

```
 <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
```

properties="hostName=localhost, port=40001, socketTimeoutMillis=12000" />

```
<defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="100" overflowToDisk="false" />
```

```
<cache name="messagesCache" maxElementsInMemory="10" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false">
<cacheEventListenerFactory
   class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
   properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true, replicateUpdates=true,
                        replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true " />
  <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" />
 </cache>
```

on second server ports are interchanged but when i run this app. i got this exception always 
WARN  [net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator]: Unable to send message to remote peer.  Message was: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ehcache.nagarroRMI.model.Message (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Comment: I am also facing similar issue, no clues yet